# pax-logging-log4j2 is not stopping in PaxExam+Karaf

Tags: log4j2, apache-karaf, pax-exam, ops4j

I am running test cases with paxexam+karaf, but after test execution when paxexam try to stop log42 bundle during containaer shutting it got stuck and stay on below line

I am using Paxexam 4.11

```
DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | util                             | 14 - org.apache.aries.util - 1.1.3 | BundleEvent STOPPING - org.apache.aries.util
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | util                             | 14 - org.apache.aries.util - 1.1.3 | BundleEvent STOPPED - org.apache.aries.util
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | Deployer                         | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.0 | Usage for bundle org.apache.felix.fileinstall [9] is 1
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | Deployer                         | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.0 | Currently selecting bundle org.apache.felix.fileinstall [9] for destroy (with reference [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationListener, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.ArtifactListener, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.ArtifactInstaller])
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | Deployer                         | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.0 | Selected bundle [org.apache.felix.fileinstall [9]] for destroy (lowest ranking service)
 INFO  | features-2-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.0 |   org.apache.felix.fileinstall/3.6.4
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | fileinstall                      | 9 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.6.4 | BundleEvent STOPPING - org.apache.felix.fileinstall
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | fileinstall                      | 9 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.6.4 | ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING - [org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService] - org.apache.felix.fileinstall
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | fileinstall                      | 9 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.6.4 | ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING - [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationListener, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.ArtifactListener, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.ArtifactInstaller] - org.apache.felix.fileinstall
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | fileinstall                      | 9 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.6.4 | ServiceEvent UNREGISTERING - [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory] - org.apache.felix.fileinstall
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | fileinstall                      | 9 - org.apache.felix.fileinstall - 3.6.4 | BundleEvent STOPPED - org.apache.felix.fileinstall
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | Deployer                         | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.0 | Usage for bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [6] is 0
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | Deployer                         | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.0 | Usage for bundle org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-log4j2 [7] is 1
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | Deployer                         | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.0 | Selected bundles [org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [6]] for destroy (no services in use)
 INFO  | features-2-thread-1 | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 10 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.2.0 |   org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api/1.10.1
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | pax-logging-api                  | 6 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.10.1 | BundleEvent STOPPING - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api
 INFO  | features-2-thread-1 | Activator                        | 6 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.10.1 | Disabling SLF4J API support.
 INFO  | features-2-thread-1 | Activator                        | 6 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.10.1 | Disabling Jakarta Commons Logging API support.
 INFO  | features-2-thread-1 | Activator                        | 6 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.10.1 | Disabling Log4J API support.
 INFO  | features-2-thread-1 | Activator                        | 6 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.10.1 | Disabling Avalon Logger API support.
 INFO  | features-2-thread-1 | Activator                        | 6 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.10.1 | Disabling JULI Logger API support.
 INFO  | features-2-thread-1 | Activator                        | 6 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.10.1 | Disabling Log4J v2 API support.
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | pax-logging-api                  | 6 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.10.1 | BundleEvent STOPPED - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api
 DEBUG | features-2-thread-1 | pax-logging-log4j2               | 7 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-log4j2 - 1.10.1 | BundleEvent STOPPING - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-log4j2
```

Regards,